# From Node upload binary to J2ee and get a response

Tags: node.js, servlets, express, httpresponse

I have a Node express server, which receives a binary file (pdf) from the client. I need to send the binary file as it is to a Java servlet. I am using the below code to do this (using request module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

```
var req = require('request');
function upload(request, response) {
   var options = {
      headers: {
        "header1": "1"
      }
    };
//Also sending headers to j2ee/servlet
var target = req.post('http://'+servlethost+':'+servletport+'/myapp/Upload', options);
   var servletResponse = request.pipe(target); 
}
```

Once file is uploaded to the servlet, servlet sets a response and some response headers.

I was hoping that servletResponse variable in node would get the response set by the servlet, along with the headers set by servlet but that's not the case. When I print servletReponse, it seems it's just the request object.

How can I get access to the response send by Servlet within Node?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by `res.headers` after getting response from your `servlet`

Try this

```
var req = require('request');
function upload(request, response) {
   var options = {
      headers: {
        "header1": "1"
      }
    };
//Also sending headers to j2ee/servlet
req.post('http://'+servlethost+':'+servletport+'/myapp/Upload', options,function(err,res,body){
console.log(res.headers);
console.log(body);
});
}
```

Comment: Can I still pipe the binary data and send that to the servlet?

Comment: You will get the response whatever sent by `servlet` in `body`